# Log4j doesn't write in file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to write a log in a file with log4j-1.2.8.jar.

Here is my log4j.properties file that is in the classpath

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\temp\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.logger.mypackage.com=DEBUG, myappender
log4j.additivity.mypackage.com=false

log4j.appender.myappender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender.datePattern='-'dd'.log'
log4j.appender.myappender.File=C:\\temp\\loging2.log
log4j.appender.myappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6r %d{ISO8601} %-5p %40.40c %x - %m\n
```

And this is a fragment of the java code where I try to output into the file:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable
{
    private static Logger logger=Logger.getRootLogger();

    ....
    private void myMethod() {
    ....

        logger.info("info"+sql);

    ....

    }

}
```

The file is not created and the only output I get is in the Console. 
Is there anything wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: It worked fine for me. No problems with your code at all.

Comment: Could your temp be windows/temp?

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue and noticed that the issues is with the .jars attached. If you are using slf4j with log4j, then remove slf4j-simple.jar (if added) and make sure you have slf4j-log4j12-xx.jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from one of our log4j properties file:

> log4j.appender.ConsoleFileAppender.File=${user.home}/.bqjdbc/bqjdbconsole.log

This will makes logfile under user.home, so it is runnable on linux too.
If your username is "JEFF" on windows then this will make a folder under the following path:

```
C:\Users\JEFF\
```

Hopefully this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your code **AS IT IS**. And it worked perfectly fine.

Try to change path of log files, probably you don't have permission to write at those locations.

Answer (score 0):

Code works just fine, so you are missing something.
Make sure the file name is correct log4j.properties (for example in netbeans a common error is to create a properties file e put the properties extension thus resulting in log4j.properties.properties)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to the answers above, make sure the `log4j.properties` file is stored in the src folder. Otherwise it wont be picked up, and the default will be called.